# Guidance on how to use blocking actor?

Tags: scala, actor

I'm struggling to find examples, blogs etc that explain how to use the `!?` operator to send a blocking message to an actor in Scala. When I (naively) try to simply use it, expecting it to block until the actor has actioned the message, the thread just blocks. Eg.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A extends Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        case 5 => println("hello")
      }
    }
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@10115870

scala> a.start
res5: scala.actors.Actor = A@10115870

scala> a !? 5
hello
Execution interrupted by signal. // I just pressed Ctrl+C
```

I can't find anything in my edition of Programming Scala and I'm probably just being stupid, but could somebody point me in the right direction?

From what I can glean from the API docs I need the blocking actor to send a message back to the caller? But how and where does the caller receive this message? Any links to examples etc would be appreciated. Unfortunately googling for `!?` is less than helpful.

Comment: what happens if you change the `react` to `receive` and use a while loop? I think you are using a threadless actor so it might be part of the issue...

Comment: I'll try it - but I need to use `react` rather than `receive` as I'll be creating lots of these actors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sender receives the message as the return value of `!?`. So

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.actors.Actor._
class A extends Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        case 5 => println("hello"); reply(0)
      }
    }
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@10115870

scala> a.start
res5: scala.actors.Actor = A@10115870

scala> a !? 5
hello
res6: Any = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That secret `reply` method was just what I was looking for.